# How to use a JQuery click event to render JSON data?

Tags: jquery, json, api, onclicklistener

*** I am not lazy -- I have read many support threads but did not understand them or know how to extrapolate to my code. I am new to this and would appreciate kind guidance. ***

I have consumed API data from a job board. I have the data rendering. I want the job description to be hidden and show only when an user clicks on the button. I am attempting to accomplish this with JQuery. I have tried out some JQuery code and it worked with hard coded data and an alert(). Now, I need to figure out how to make it work with the API data that I have consumed which is in the JSON format.

Using JQuery, how do I get the job description from my json data to show only when the button is clicked?

I have attempted to have `description='';` where the hard coded data once was and I added `$(document.body).append(event.data.description);`to render the data (in place of where the alert() was)

Here is the JQUERY code:

```
// JQUERY EVENT HANDLER 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#btnClickMe').on('click', {
     description: '',

  }, jobDesc);

  function jobDesc(event)
  {
    $(document.body).append(event.data.description);

  }
});

Here is my HTML:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

 <title>JQuery Testing</title>  

</head>
  <body>

   <!-- DIV FOR CARD DISPLAY -->
     <div id="root"></div>

     <!-- CARD -->
     <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class = "card">
        <input id="btnClickMe" type="button" value="Click Me"/>
     </div>
   </div>

   </body>
</html>
```

Here is my full code on codepen: https://codepen.io/CodeDuchess/pen/jRRvgy

Expected results are that when the button is clicked, it will show the full job description (it does not have to open in a new Window).

Actual results are that nothing happens when the button is clicked and the job description is there when the page is first loaded.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks so much!!

Comment: This is several questions. All of the answers can be found here on SO if you take the time to look for them one step at a time.

Comment: I am working on an answer for you right now. I'll "jQuery-ify" this code for you and that should give you a great start on using jQuery.

Comment: @TimothyWood Thank you! I appreciate your time.

Comment: No problem. If my answer was good - please mark it if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go. The following should serve as a decent example on how to do all of this in jQuery. Also see the code pen of the working example here: https://codepen.io/xonosnet/pen/PgvaWq

**CSS**

```
.hidden {
  display:none!important;
}
.card:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

**JS**

```
'use strict';


//Clean up API URL to make it easy to configure.
var app = {
        baseUrl : 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://jobs.github.com/',
        target: 'positions.json',
        params : {
            markdown:true,
            location:'united states',
            page:1,
            count:20
        },
        url : '',
        data : '',
        root : $('#root')
    };
    app.url = app.baseUrl+app.target+'?'+$.param(app.params); //$.param() encodes the params object to be used in the http request.

app.root.append('<div class="container1"></div>'); //Easy way to append inline html to an existing element.
var container1 = $('.container1'); //Reference the newly created element by class using css selectors. You can reference elements by any attribute.


//$.getJSON() is a quick & easy way to retrieve JSON through an http request.
var request = $.getJSON(app.url, function(data) {
    app.data = data; //This executes first
}).done(function() { //This executes second - This is called chaining.
    console.log('[SUCCESS] Found '+app.data.length+' jobs!');
    //$.each() will iterate objects & arrays.
    $.each(app.data, function(index, job) {
        const output = [
            '<div class="card" data-id="">',
            '   <h2>'+job.title.substring(0, 40)+(job.title.length > 40 ? '...':'')+'</h2>',
            '   <h3>'+job.company+'</h3>',
            '   <h4>'+job.type+'</h4>',
            '   <h5>'+job.location+'</h5>',
            '   <p class="job-desc hidden">'+job.description.substring(0, 300)+(job.description.length > 300 ? '...':'')+'</p>',
            '</div>'
        ]; // This is one among many ways to build out html. I chose this because it's cheap & clean.
        container1.append(output.join('')); //Join the array into a string & append it to container1.
    });
});

// This will toggle the "hidden" class of the child nodes of any card that you click.
// A cleaner way of showing job details rather than displaying a button.
$(document).on('click', '.card', function() {
    var children = $(this).find('.job-desc');
    children.toggleClass('hidden');
});

//If you still want to use a button, this is how you can do that.
//Assuming the following exists in each card: <button class="show-job-btn">Click Me!</button>
$(document).on('click', '.show-job-btn', function() {
    var children = $(this).closest('.job-desc');
    children.toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

Comment: This worked beautifully! I also appreciate the clarity you provided via lots of comments. You are a great teacher!! I wish I could buy you a drink! I did upvote your solution but it did not show up on my end. Thanks so much and have a great week!

Comment: I'm happy to help. You should be able to mark the post as the answer somewhere. That'd help me out a lot! :)

Comment: It has been checked as the solution!